# Copy of rows of data meeting date range criteria using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to amend code I have to limit the results copied to another worksheet. Right now everything is copied that is > today. It's comparing an expiry date in Column H with today's date. I want to limit the results to include all rows that include an expiry date of > today AND < today + 60 days. I've tried different ways and functions like defining an end date and used the DateAdd function. Nothing is working, please help! Thank you!

```
Sub SearchForExpiryDate()

       Dim LSearchRow As Integer
       Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

       On Error GoTo Err_Execute

       'Start search in row 8
       LSearchRow = 8

       'Start copying data to row 2 in Expiring MOCs (row counter variable)
       LCopyToRow = 2


       While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0


          'If value in column H > Today, copy entire row to "Expiring_MOC"
          If Range("H" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value > Now() Then

             'Select row in MOC_MASTER to copy
             Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
             Selection.Copy

             'Paste row into "Expiring_MOCs" in next row
             Sheets("Expiring_MOCs").Select
             Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
             ActiveSheet.Paste

             'Move counter to next row
             LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

             'Go back to 'MOC MASTER' to continue searching
             Sheets("MOC_MASTER").Select

          End If

          LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

       Wend

       'Position on cell A3
       Application.CutCopyMode = False
       Range("A3").Select

       MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

       Exit Sub

    Err_Execute:
       MsgBox "An error occurred."

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the following line is working under the old conditions,

```
If Range("H" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value > Now() Then
```

... change it to include the new conditions (60 day limit)

```
If Range("H" & LSearchRow).Value > Now() AND _
  Range("H" & LSearchRow).Value < Now() + 60 Then
```

The `CStr` conversion wasn't completely necessary for a simple string concatenation.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thank you. I have tried this, but it's returning rows containing expiry dates 1 year from now and not the desired 2 month range. Thanks though!

Comment: If that is the case then you may have dates with swapped MDY vs DMY.

Comment: would `dateadd("d",60,now())` work regardless of date style in place of the  `now() + 60`?

Comment: It would work if `Now() + 60` worked. If the dates are wrong, then they are wrong. They need to be imported properly or manually corrected.

Comment: @Jeeped  Thanks, I do not work much with dates and wanted to know if it made a difference.

Comment: Thank you both. The dates in the worksheet display in format DMY. But the macro returns rows in DMY as well as in YMD past 60 days, e.g., 2016-05-31. Maybe it has an issue recognizing the date format or the date format is not properly enforced. If I select a date cell in the original it comes up in the function box (sorry don't know the proper term) as MDY. How do I enforce the date format properly instead of it just displaying DMY but not storing it that way in the cell.

Comment: I've tried it also with the dateadd function now as well as per Scott's suggestion and I get the same result as with now() + 60. Why is it not recognizing the dates? I get returns way past 60 days all the way up to 2017.

Comment: a) are half of the dates right-aligned in their cells and the other half left-aligned? b) it may be time to redact a portion of the data in the worksheet and post it to a public file repository like Google-Drive or DropBox.

Comment: a) the data does not indicate any alignment. they are definitely dates, not text.

Comment: b) I will try but I have to desensitize the data first as it is work stuff